# plotting smoothed lines in qplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, line

My issue is that I'd like to know how to plot smoothed lines in qplot in R, except without the gray bands around them.  For instance, when I write this:

```
qplot(wt, mpg, data=mtcars, geom=c("smooth"), color=factor(cyl), method="lm", 
formula = y ~ ns(x,4))
```

The plot that appears has not only the three colored lines, but these large gray clouds around the lines.  How do I remove those while also keeping the smooth lines?  Geom="line" gives me very jagged lines that trace every noisy point, so those won't do either.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

add `se=FALSE`.

from page 14 of the ggplot2 book (which is expensive, but worth it).

[bdemarest - thanks for the edit! (didn't capitalize FALSE correctly)]